# Follow Condition before Submission after Triggering the Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I want to save my record by pressing F2 on my keyboard. The submit functionality using a button works fine, but I cannot replicate it using this F2 keyboard functionality. There is no problem triggering the F2 keyboard, but the problem I think relies on my code.

This is the JQuery that triggers the F2 on my keyboard:

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode);
            switch (key) {
                case 113:  //This will trigger the event once F2 on keyboard is press.
                    fncTrigger();
                    break;
                default:;
            }
        });
```

And this is the function that triggers the click event:

```
function fncTrigger() {
        $('#btnSubmit').click();
    }
```

This works fine. It will trigger the function and will trigger the submit event. Unfortunately on this click event, there is still a condition that will check something on my logic before submitting the form:

```
<button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="fncFormValidation(this);"> Submit</button>

function fncFormValidation(frm) {
        var form = $('#frmCall');
        var inpObj = document.getElementById("frmCall");

        if (inpObj.checkValidity()) {
                        form.submit();
                    }
            } else {
                console.log('Please correct validation errors');
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, there is still a condition that needs to be checked before it needs to submit the form.

**This works fine when I click the button, but when I press the F2 on my keyboard, regardless if the condition of if-else is true or not, it will automatically submit the form.**

I tried to use event.preventDefault() but still it will submit the form once I press the F2 on my keyboard. Is there a way that it will follow the condition inside fncFormValidation and prevent submitting the form if the condition is not met?

Comment: You will need to call the `fncFormValidation` from your keyup event handler.  If in addition to canceling the event you changed that method to return a true/false depending on if it cancelled it or not, then the keyup event could do the submit only if that method returned true.  Or actually it does the submit() as part of it's logic, so you might not need to return a boolean at all.

Comment: I tried that but I am not sure why the HTML validation is not working when I call that on the keyup event handler. That's why I force it by calling the button directly.

Comment: Because that validation is on the button as a click event binding.  Not as a keyup binding.  Ah, I see what you are doing

Comment: `function fncTrigger() {
        if(document.getElementById("frmCall").checkValidity())
        $('#btnSubmit').click();
         else console.log("Erros")
    }` ?

Comment: I'd suggest two things.  Put a console.log in the validation method to verify that the logic is not happening with the $().click().  If it is indeed not happening, try changing `$('#btnSubmit').click();` to `$('#btnSubmit')[0].click();` to invoke the native click rather than the jQuery click.